# Как правильно говорить

Tags: общие-вопросы

Выполнял заказ в виде изготовления логотипа для одной кинокомпании. Частью логотипа была надпись "Форум в киностудии". Одолели сомнения по поводу написания.

Как правильно говорить: "форум в кинокостудии"  или "на киностудии"?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3):

Если это кинокомпания," Форум в киностудии " вполне корректно: в объединении кинематографистов, в помещении, принадлежащем киностудии. Когда говорят "поедем на киностудию", имеют в виду "на площадку киностудии", это тоже корректно. Для логотипа я бы выбрала всё-таки предлог "В"-"в сообществе кинематографистов".